# meteor onDataAdded getting list but not able to pass to Base Adapter

Tags: android, meteor, ddp

In Meteor on to get list from server `onDataAdded` override method calls again until list end so in that if I pass array value to adapter it will call again and again.

My code:

```
@Override
public void onDataAdded(String s, String s1, String s2) {
    Log.d("onDataAdded",""+s);
    //lists is collection name
    if(s.contains("lists")) {
        arrayList.add(s1)
        adapter= new customAdapter(this,arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
}
```

If I am calling :

```
adapter= new customAdapter(this,arrayList);
list.setAdapter(adapter)
```

`onDataAdded` method of Meteor adapter is setting again and again until its reach last value is there any way to set adapter once by getting size or any another way please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the adapter once inside `onCreate` method and then use `notifyDataSetChanged` method to notify the `adapter` about any changes in the dataset.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onDataAdded(String s, String s1, String s2) {
    Log.d("onDataAdded",""+s);

    //lists is collection name
    if(s.contains("lists")) {
        arrayList.add(s1);
        // notify the adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```